# Simple WPF data binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I want to separate my user interface from my code, so I (obviously) landed at bindings. As a test, I've written the following XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="BindingTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="Auto" Width="200">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Item}"/>
        <Button Content="Add" Click="AddNew"/>
        <ListBox Height="100" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The C# looks like this:

```
namespace BindingTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public string Item { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        }

        private void AddNew(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Items.Add(Item);
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to happen is that the text entered into the textbox is added to the listbox's itemssource. However, this doesn't happen...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things you need two do -

1. Set - `DataContext = this;` in your constructor.
2. You'd be better off if you would change your properties to dependency properties instead. You could do that easily with the "propdp" snippet in visual studio.

Comment: There is no need to change the property to dependency property. DP is some what heavier than Normal Property. Instead just implement INotifyProertyChanged that will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Data binding is performed against the current data context. However, you have not set the data context for your window. Often you will set the data context to a view model but in your case you simply want to use the window class for that.

You should add the following line to the constructor:

```
DataContext = this;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public string Item { get; set; } 
        public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; set; } 
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); 
            Items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        private void AddNew(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Items.Add(Item);
        }
    }
}
```

You do need to set your DataContext - works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. You should set the correct data context for your window. Otherwise the binding will not find your properties.
2. You should initialize your Items collection **before** the `InitializeComponent()` call as inside it the ListBox tries to evaluate the expression and get NULL as the binding souce. And since you are not implementing INotifyPropertyChanged and the property is not a DependencyProperty the ListBox will never reevaluate the binding thus it will never get the instance of your Items collection.

So, the code should be as follows:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent(); 
    }
```

Comment: Calling `InitializeComponent` in the beginning of the constructor works fine.

Comment: How can it work fine? ItemsSource is bound to Items. Inside the `InitializeComponent` the binding returns NULL since the Items collection is not initialized and the ListBox gets that value. After this point setting Items to some other value (e.g. `new ObsColl<string>) will not update the binding since there are no mechanisms implemented to support that (no INPC, no DP). So - how can it possibly work fine without implementing INPC or DP?

Comment: Well, wasted 10 minutes to try it out. Try #1: InitializeComponent(), set DataContext, set Items => does not work; Try #2 (just to be sure):  InitializeComponent(), set Items, set DataContext => does not work; Try #3: Set Items, set DataContext, InitializeComponent() => Works :). I do not know what tools you are using, but it just cannot work. Explain how would it work in your case.

Comment: I'm using the exact same source code as given in the question except I assign `this` to `DataContext` in the end of the constructor. If you add `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High` to the `ItemsSource` binding you will see `Resolve source deferred` being logged when `InitializeComponent` is being called and then after the constructor has completed `Resolving source`. So basically data binding will attempt lazy binding if the binding source is `null`.

Comment: Oh wait, I take the blame now - I had ElementName in the bindings. So yes, you are completely correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

hope this will work. But this is not hte right approach. You need to set the DataContext to the Object whose properties u guna use for binding. you must follow MVVM Architecture.

Comment: <TextBox Text="{Binding Item,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}, Mode=FindAncestor}"/>

Comment: <ListBox Height="100" ItemsSource="{Binding Items,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}, Mode=FindAncestor}"/>